# Append byte array as unicode character(s) to a string and display it and write that string back to a file

Tags: java, string, unicode, arrays

I have byte array `E2 80 94` which means long dash "\u2014". I want to append those bytes to a string so that I see long dash when I display it. How do I do that? After displaying it, howdo I write string to a file so that long dash is stored as `E2 80 94`?

My bytes vary in length: 1 - 8 bytes. I want to write them literally to a string (and then that string to a file). I have no means to know if those bytes are one character or multiple. I am reading them from a binary file(.mobi).

"0x01 to 0x08: "literals": the byte is interpreted as a count from 1 to 8, and that many literals are copied unmodified from the compressed stream to the decompressed stream." -WikiBooks, PalmDoc Compression

Comment: FYI, your byte encoding is `UTF-8`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build easily a String with

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29

and then operate with it.  Make sure to identify properly the encoding of your binary array in order for the constructor to work